# How do I Include spaces between my integers as output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    int input {};
    int sum {0};

    cout << "Number: ";
    cin >> input;

    while (input != 0) {
        sum = sum + (input%10);
        input = input / 10;

    }
    cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;
}
```

I've already got my input of integers to add up to its sum so For Example:
Input: 982
Ouput: The sum is = 19 (9 + 8 + 2)

But my teacher wants me to also get the Output: 9 8 2 with the integers being spaced out.
Is it unwise to use my input as an integer? I see people using char and strings and then convert it to integers but I do not understand it can someone please explain it to me or elaborate on how to get my input of integer to be spaced out or have another way of solving it. Also if the user inputs a negative number it must be converted into a positive number;

Comment: are you talking about spacing for inputs or outputs?

Comment: Spacing for Outputs

Comment: check my answer. It accepts strings as input, converts it into integers and then does the sum

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a space into a character stream like this:

```
std::cout << ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to use string insert with space in between:

```
int main () {
  int input {};
  int sum {0};
  cout << "Number: ";
  cin >> input;
  string in;

  while (input != 0) {
    sum += (input%10);
    in.insert(0, ' ' + to_string(input % 10));
    input /= 10;
  }

  cout << "The sum is: " << sum << endl;
  cout << "Integer with space:" << in;
}
```

Output:

```
The sum is: 19
Integer with space: 9 8 2
```

Comment: @Evg yes, simpler.

Comment: For some reason its not working for me when I copy and paste it in? It says all have failed

Comment: @naustin288, Here is the [execution code](https://ideone.com/jl6XKo) as above.